# How to kill an application permanently? 

Tags: android

In my application when I give valid input in url  is work fine and give response.When I give invalid input its shows toast message invalid input.But if I give again a valid input again , it show the invalid input message , why is this happening ?
Is there anywhere save history ??

```
xmlResponse = A("www.xyz/AgMainServlet?messageType=MIN&pin=" +    
    txtPinno.getText().toString() + "&mobile=" + AgAppHelperMethods.varMobileNo + 
"&source="  + AgAppHelperMethods.varMobileNo + "&channel=INTERNET");
```

Comment: Can u give us some more code..so that v can look into the matter !!

Comment: Could be a cache issue. Try appending a random number/string to your URL. Also, the title and the rest of the question are talking about totally different things.

Comment: actully is very long  code  my application get xml response from server after valid input but when i give wrong input is print toast message invalid input but if i give again valid input is still show invalid input tell me why??

Comment: Since you talk about inputs, let us know how you specify the checks for valid inputs.

Answer (score 1):

To kill an application permanently, just finish all the existing activities. If you don't have track of unfinished activities, just start an activity with flag 'CLEAR_TOP' and then finish that activity. This should kill you application.